# Write javascript commands on a render() component method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I'm trying to return an HTML element or another depending on some conditions calculated on Javascript. I tried doing this, but I can't start the condition with and if, I don't understand why.
My component file is this one:

```
import React from 'react';
import defaultImage from './defaultImage.jpg';

export default class Game extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const image = this.props.question.attachment.url;
        const tips = this.props.question.tips;

        return (
            <div className="flexDisplay">
                <img src={image === (null || "") ? defaultImage : image} className="questionImage centerVertical" alt="Error loading, just read the question" />
                <div className="centerHorizontal centerVertical">
                    <h1>{this.props.question.question}</h1>
                    <h2 className="centerHorizontal">Pistas:</h2>   
                    {   
                        if(tips.length === 0){ //The problem comes here
                            return <div>No hay pistas disponibles</div>
                        }else{
                            tips.map((tip, i,) => {
                                return <div className="centerHorizontal" key={tip.toString()}>{i+1}. {tip}</div>;
                            })
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Anyone spot the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ReactJS's component ( JSX ) you are not allowed to use anything else than a statement that returns a value.

You can imagine the logic by trying to assign a variable :

```
const result = if ( a ) { "b" } else { "c" } // won't work
```

But on the other hand with a [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) it will.

```
const result = a ? "b" : "c";
```

So in your case there are two ways of achieving the goal :

```
{ tips.length === 0 ? ( <div>No hay pistas disponibles</div> ) : (
     tips.map((tip, i) => ( 
         <div className="centerHorizontal" key={ tip.toString() }>{i+1}. {tip}</div>
     ) )
) }
```

Or you can simply extract that in a method

```
renderTips( tips ) {
    if ( tips.length === 0 ) { return null; }
    return tips.map( ( tip, i ) => (
        <div className="centerHorizontal" key={ tip.toString() }>{i+1}. {tip}</div>
    );
}

render() {
   ...
   return (
       ...
       { this.renderTips( tips ) }
   )
}
```

Comment: Just something worth noting is that if they decided to use a ternary inside JSX, they could also do something like:
`{tips.length === 0 && <div>No hay pistas disponibles</div>}` which would return the div if `tips.length` is zero. For this specific case, they'd have to have two of these, which is not ideal, but it could be worth mentioning it!

Answer (score 4):

You can not use `if` statements inside JSX syntax. Instead you can use the ternary operator which basically accomplish the same :

```
{
tips.length === 0 ? 
  (<div>No hay pistas disponibles</div>)
: (tips.map((tip, i,) => {
  return <div className="centerHorizontal" key={tip.toString()}>{i+1}. {tip}</div>;
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not able to use "if" in inline conditional statements in jsx. You can however use the ternary syntax instead:

```
{   
    tips.length === 0 ? (
        return <div>No hay pistas disponibles</div>
    ) : (
        tips.map((tip, i,) => {
            return <div className="centerHorizontal" key={tip.toString()}>{i+1}. {tip}</div>;
        })
    )
}
```

You can read more about using inline conditional statements here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator